# ASM code not compiling due to "field not visible"

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I haven't been able to find **anything** about this, so I thought I'd ask here: I'm using ASM to change a field in an external library from private to public. The problem, as would be expected, is that although the code would *run*, it doesn't compile because the JDK doesn't know about the modifications I've made until runtime.

Is there a way to tell the JDK about my modifications? And if so, is there a way to make Eclipse know about the changes too?

I'm using Gradle to build, if that makes any difference.

Comment: ASM doesn’t say what you’re going to do with the created bytecode. You can use it to define runtime classes, but you also can store the result into class files and pass them to `javac` or any other tool… Besides that, I strongly suggest rethinking your strategy. Having to hack an external library to use it, suggests that you are either, using the library wrong or using the wrong library for your job.

Comment: This is a bad idea but I've used it temporarily once. Make a class and add a field of the type and name you want to access. Your code should point to this class. When your code is loaded swap the field owner to the targeted library class. you must also make sure the target field's access has been made public.